# Finding buttons on a webpage using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate a web based application and I am having trouble finding buttons in order to click on them.

Basically there are a number of text boxes on a screen and next to each text box is a "Go" button. Once you hit the "Go" a popup will be overlayed on the screen saying "Are you Sure?" and 2 buttons Yes/No. Where I am getting stuck is after the first set of buttons on the Yes/No popup buttons. Each button has a non-unique class name and no name variable, so I am finding each button by its tagName and then clicking on the relevant element

```
WebElement aButtons = driver.findElements(By.tagName("button");
aButtons .get(x).click();
```

This works until aButtons .get(x).click(); throws an exception saying the element isn't clickable. On further inspection of aButtons  it has a size of 78 elements, despite there being only 33 visable buttons on the page.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to find my buttons better? Or perhaps how to handle the exception such that I can, with a bit of trial and error, find the element? If the exception could be ignored, I could probably use a for loop in increments of 10 in order to find which element the Yes/No buttons correspond to.

If I ruled the world I would go to the developer of this webpage and ask them to make the buttons more easily identifiable, but that unfortunately is out of the question

When I inspect the elements in question this is the block in the html that gets highlighted

"Go" button:

```
<
button type "submit" ng-click="vm.click()" ng-disabled = "vm.isDisabled()" 
class = "btn btn"> Generate <button/
>
<
button class ="btn" ng-show="vm.runScripts" ng-click="vm.runScript()" ng-
disabled ="vm.runScript.isScriptRunning">
>span class = "glyphicon play" aria-hidden="true"></span>
Yes
</button>
```

I was having trouble with the formatting of the above since I am unfamiliar with posting html code.v the 2nd button is the yes button.

(Note the "No" button has the same "btn" class name). When I tried to find the element based off of the class name " glyphicon play" I got an error saying compound class names are not valid. I was able to find the "Go" buttons since they were sequential, so like aButtons .get(1).click(); was the first Go button on the page, aButtons .get(2).click(); was the second etc.

I cannot share the url since it is an internal site.

Comment: if you could point us to the page in question it would help immensely.  Alternatively, show us some of the html on the page.  we can probably find something there that would allow you to identify the yes/no buttons that are currently visible on the page.

Comment: Share the relevant HTML and your code trials.